# Ursina update function within class

Tags: python, function, class, ursina

In a project I am working on, I have multiple classes in which I wish to each have an update function when an object is created. How do I get these update functions to run every frame? i.e for this example code, how do I get both class a and b to run update functions?

```
from ursina import *
app = Ursina()

class a:
    def update(self):
        print("a updating")

class b:
    def update(self):
        print("b updating")

a = a()
b = b()

app.run()
```

At the moment neither function gets run. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Every time a object gets created the `__init__` method is called. So you can do some initalization there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For update to run automatically it has to be on an Entity. Simply inherit Entity like this:

```py
class A(Entity):
    def update(self):
        print('update')
```

The way this works is that when you instantiate an Entity, ursina will add it to a list (scene.entities). Every frame ursina will loop through that list and call entity.update() if that entity has a method named `update`